# Php localhost ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: php

I am working on my localhost. I created two files. My main page name is index.php. The page has loaded I want to direct to my defined url.  But I got "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" message. I changed my php ini file setting output_buffering=ON. But I got same error message. How can I prevent this one?

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');  
header('Location:http://localhost/php/getjs/index.php?start=main'); 
if (isset($_GET["start"])){
    $main=$_GET["start"];
    if ($main==="main"){
        include 'file.php';      
    }
}
 if (isset($_GET["start"])){
    $main=$_GET["start"];
    if ($main==="list"){
        include 'file2.php';     
    }           
}   
?>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="list" value="Load File2">
<script>
 $("#list").click(function(){
    window.location.href="http://localhost/php/getjs/index.php?start=list";        
 });
</script>
```

Comment: You code constantly redirects with that header line. You can prevent it be only calling it when you actually want to redirect.

Comment: I want to direct one time. When index.php had loaded it must go to index.php?start=main. İs there another for this?

Comment: If you review my edit, you will probably notice the difference in approach... It will at least stop the redirects, but may also shed some light on why the redirects happen... ;)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much it is working. :) İf you post your answer to my answer I can accept your answer or not you know.